# React-map-gl cannot fit within parent <div>

Tags: reactjs, react-map-gl

I'm starting to play with react-map-gl.
I followed the example in https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl.

It worked fine.
However, the size of the map overflows all the way to the right & bottom of my page.
the  component is currently inside in a parent div.
However i can't seem to contained it within the parent div.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Share relevant code please

Comment: Hi Hyetigran, i posted my code below

Comment: Looks like there might be a solution in a previous post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098219/how-to-make-child-divs-always-fit-inside-parent-div

I recommend opening up your browser dev tools and tinker with element styles in a trial & error fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying with below code:

```
<div className="relative w-full h-full mr-10 pr-10" ref={targetRef}>
    <ReactMapGL
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11"
        mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
        onViewportChange={handleViewportChange}
        {...viewport}
    />
</div>
```

I'm using tailwindcss.
The map is rendered to fill all the screen.
I'm trying to add margin or padding on the right, however it doesn't work.
I could add left margin though.